# Creating more than one hidden layer Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm creating a neural network from scratch (without being able to use any existing frameworks) and I was wondering how it would be able to make the constructor hold a variable amount of Hidden Layers? I've created one so far but I'm a bit stuck on how to extend it to multiple hidden layers. (Being done on Python)

Edit:

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, input_len, hidden_units, output_len,
                 act_func = None, loss_func=None,
                 init_weights=np.zeros, output_func=None,
                 random_seed=None):

        if random_seed:
            np.random_seed(random_seed)

        self.loss_func = loss_func
        self.output_func = output_func
        self.L = len(hidden_units) + 2  # change this later
        self.layers = []

        input_layer = Layer(np.identity(input_len),
                            np.zeros(input_len), id_f)
        self.layers.append(input_layer)

        for neurons, func in zip(hidden_units, act_func):
            prev_neurons = self.layers[-1].num_neurons
            weight_mat = init_weights((neurons,prev_neurons))
            biases = init_weights((neurons, ))
            current_layer = Layer(weight_mat, biases, func)
            self.layers.append(current_layer)
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut added the constructor

Comment: Indentation is broken. Please fix first.

Comment: Your question sounds pretty much as if you didn't know how to pass dictionaries / lists to a function.